# Get description from the second drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, select, post, drop-down-menu

I have a form with two select menus !
The first one **"cat"** is loaded automatically from database. The second one **"soucat"** is loaded automatically using Javascript when an item is selected from the first select menu.

The problem is that I can't get the description from the second select menu to send it via `$_POST`!

```
<form method="post" action="" oninput="">
<label>
    <select name="cat" id="cat" onChange="getcat()">
        <option value="-1">Categories</option>
        <?php
        /* Fill in the drop down menu from database */
        ?>       
    </select>
</label>

<label id="souscat">
    <select id="soucat" name="soucat">
        <option value='-1'>SubCategories</option> 
    </select>
</label>

<span class="fieldd" id="searchformm">
    <input type="text" name="searchterm" id="searchterm" placeholder="Product to find ?" />
    <button type="submit" class="monboutton" >Find !</button>
</span>

</form>
```

Now, I've set the code to store informations contained in the form :

```
<?php                                           
unset($cat); 
if(isset($_POST['cat'])) {$cat = explode('|', $_POST['cat']);}
else      $cat="";

unset($soucat); 
if(isset($_POST['soucat'])) {$soucat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['soucat']);}
else      {$soucat=""; echo "soucat still empty";}

unset($searchterm); 
if(isset($_POST['searchterm'])) {$searchterm =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searchterm']);}
else      $searchterm="";
?>
```

And now we test and we see :

```
echo  "The category is: ".$cat[1]."<br>";
echo  "The sub category is: ".$soucat."<br>";
echo "The searchterm is: ".$searchterm."<br>";
```

`$cat[1]` and `$searchterm` are containing descriptions they must contain. But `$soucat` is always empty! I don't know how to deal with this problem.

Comment: Can you post `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Think that the problem is the missing S :-)
Sometimes you call it **`$soucat`** and sometimes **`$souscat`**.
You post **soucat** and look for **souscat**.